# Looking for a good annotation tool for PDF documents on Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, pdf, adobe-reader, annotations

I noticed that on my Mac, the program *Preview* allows you annotate PDF documents. If I open up the same PDF file in Adobe Reader on the PC, I can see the annotations in the *Comments* pane, but I cannot create new ones. I'm guessing that both programs are using some standard defined in PDF documents for annotations.

I'm wondering if there is any good utility that is similar to *Preview* on the Mac, which will allow me to make annotations. Since *Preview* is free on the Mac, I'm hoping to find a similar free solution for the PC.

I noticed on the [comparison page of Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/matrix.html), that the Pro and Pro Extended versions allow you to make a document annotatable by Adobe Reader users. If a product simply enables this feature on a PDF document, it would be a good solution as well, since then I can use Adobe Reader for annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free:

- [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/) 2.0 or greater.

Paid:

- [nitro pdf](http://www.nitropdf.com/)
- [pdf xchange](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-lite)

Comment: It would be nice if you provided the links.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar, don't forget that this also a wiki :). Links added.

Answer (score 0):

The free [Nitro Reader](http://www.nitroreader.com/) supports annotations.

(I haven't actually used it much yet; just installed it yesterday.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro, you can use the tiny Typewriter tool to annotate documents. At least on my Windows version.