# Tool to annotate and format PDF

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a good annotation tool for PDF documents on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/155181/looking-for-a-good-annotation-tool-for-pdf-documents-on-windows)

i am looking for a preferably free tool to re-format and annotate PDF documents. the reason why i want to format text is that some documents/book's text is too close to each other. `line-height` in CSS. annotate is mainly to summarize and take notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Foxit PDF creator [from here](http://www.foxitsoftware.com)

It's not free but I think they provide trial.